# Get the entrance point from a straight line in a rectangle

Tags: trigonometry

The rectangle is like a street. The right half is to go upwards, the left half to go down. The red lines are paths of vehicles. And my goal is to give every vehicle the right lane. So when you look at my picture and a vehicle is entering from the top of the rectangle, it has to take the left lane. When it is entering from the bottom it has to take the right lane.
So basically I think I have to get the information on which half of the rectangle the vehicle enters and then I know on which lane to go.

What I was doing is to calculate the angles from the red line and the yellow line, which is just the middle of the rectangle.
I also calculated the angle between these lines, like you can see [here.](http://planetmath.org/anglebetweentwolines)

But I don't know what I could do with these angles then...
I also have to take the different quadrants into account, and the rectangle can be rotated!

Maybe I have to use the intersection point of the line with the rectangle and compute the distance to start and end of the street..

Maybe someone has a better idea for me ;)

[image]

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on what you mean by "when a vehicle is entering from the top of the rectangle, it has to take the left lane, and vice versa"?  Ostensibly the vehicles enter the rectangle from arbitrary directions.  What happens if one enteres the bottom-half of the rectangle from above (i.e. pointing down)?

Comment: Sorry, added some information. If one enteres the bottom-half of the rectangle from above, the left side should be taken because I always have to drive on the right lane.

Comment: What information to you have available to make the computation?  Do you have the dimensions of the rectangle?  Or only the yellow line?  How are the trajectories represented?  Also, again to clarify: If one enters the bottom-half of the rectangle from the bottom-left (so, moving slightly upwards and to the right), which lane does it go into?  Stated differently: Is it the *location* the "car" enters at that determines the lane, or the *direction* the car eneters at?

Comment: Its the direction the car enters that determines the lane. I also have the dimensions of the rectangle. The trajectories or paths of the cars are simple points in the coordinate system. For my tests, I used the first point of the path, that is in the rectangle and the prior point to calculate the straight line.

Comment: The problem seems to be not that trivial as I first thought it would be ;) Right now I am thinking about rotating and translating the rectangle to the first quadrant, and moving the path also. Then the problem is easier to solve I think.

Comment: If it's the direction of the car that's important, can't you just test whether the y coordinate of the velocity vector is positive or negative?

Comment: Well I have a solution now. I take the entrance and outgoing intersection points, make a line and take the angle between this line and the middle line of the street. So I am using the whole path the car should take.